# Nginx rewrite en dash in url

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I have URL:s which contain one en dash character like this:

https://domain.dom/path/document-–-name-contains-a-single-en-dash

I tried to create a rewrite to replace the '-–-' string (dash,en dash, dash) with a single dash like so:

```
rewrite ^(.*)-–-(.*)$  $1-$2;
```

...to achieve urls like so:

https://domain.dom/path/document-name-contains-a-single-en-dash

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The en-dash (assuming UTF8) is actually represented as three bytes in the URL. You can place arbitrary bytes into the regular expression by using the `\x` escape.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)-\xE2\x80\x93-(.*)$ $1-$2;
```